Public domain app triggers "Not secure or Dangerous"
I deployed this React app as a side project based on this Full Stack FastAPI template using Traefik and docker-compose. I configured Github action on Azure self-hosted VM agent. After deploying using Azure VM and Azure DNS, I keep getting this message that the site is "Not secure or Dangerous". How do i get rid of this warning message? this is the full stack Fastapi template i'm using, it has a load balancer tool "traefik" and it has a certificate. I don't think the issue is related to an https thing.
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:3.0
    ports:
      # Listen on port 80, default for HTTP, necessary to redirect to HTTPS
      - 80:80
      # Listen on port 443, default for HTTPS
      - 443:443
    restart: always
  ...
    volumes:
      # Add Docker as a mounted volume, so that Traefik can read the labels of other services
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      # Mount the volume to store the certificates
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
    command:
      # Enable Docker in Traefik, so that it reads labels from Docker services
      - --providers.docker
      # Do not expose all Docker services, only the ones explicitly exposed
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      # Create an entrypoint "http" listening on port 80
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      # Create an entrypoint "https" listening on port 443
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      # Create the certificate resolver "le" for Let's Encrypt, uses the environment variable EMAIL
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${EMAIL?Variable not set}
      # Store the Let's Encrypt certificates in the mounted volume
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      # Use the TLS Challenge for Let's Encrypt
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
      # Enable the access log, with HTTP requests
      - --accesslog
      # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
      - --log
      # Enable the Dashboard and API
      - --api
    networks:
      # Use the public network created to be shared between Traefik and
      # any other service that needs to be publicly available with HTTPS
      - traefik-public

volumes:
  # Create a volume to store the certificates, even if the container is recreated
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  # Use the previously created public network "traefik-public", shared with other
  # services that need to be publicly available via this Traefik
  traefik-public:
    external: true


see source: https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-template/blob/master/docker-compose.traefik.yml


Sounds like you're using a self-signed certificate (for your https requests). You'll need to get a generate a certificate and get it signed by a CA. And then get your server to use the certificate to identify itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656927/how-to-get-a-certificate-from-a-ca

Sounds like Traefik is using a default TLS certificate, which is not trusted by the browser. This is usually created when the domain doesn't point to the right Traefik IP or certresolver settings are wrong. Enable Traefik debug log and check for errors (err) and acme messages.
